# Restarted servers, Why cant my clients connect to my mysql DB? Getting java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, mysql

Last weekend my office had no power for a few hrs, so I had to shut down my whole system of servers/clients and java applications.  I had just fixed a db error I made, and things were all working fine. I came in Monday morning and when I tried to start up my java applications, they threw the error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: connection refused.
```

Here is what you should know:

- port 3306 is open and listening
- I am using mysql
- I am using ubuntu clients/servers

What is really confusing here is that the whole system was working on Friday, and after restarting things, now isnt...

What could cause this change?

When I run `mysql status` on a separate vm, I get

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Cant connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: port 3306 on which IP? If it's only listening for 127.0.0.1, you'll never be able to connect from external IPs.

Comment: @MarcB I dont think any of this should have changed, if it was all working fine on Friday, and broken as hell on Monday, i cant imagine that being the issue?

Comment: the system was rebooted. something changed, or wasn't committed to a startup file. don't assume nothing's different. if nothing was differen, then it'd be working.

Comment: I did drop a table and restore from about september... When I did that though, the system worked and had the restored info available...

Answer (score 0):

Either someone installed a firewall rule to block that port or more likely the mysql isn't configured to start automatically on boot.

Comment: But when i start mysql workbench, and can connect to the db, then this shouldnt fail?

Comment: Yes it should. I'd be looking at the config files instead of asking on stackoverflow. Unless you're not the one responsible for configs (in which case I'd contact the party that is).

Comment: Its all on me here. Could it be something about permissions and my clients? maybe they dont have permissions anymore. It seems that the java applications immediately get booted when try to connect to the db.

Comment: Could be, do you superuser access to the db so you can check the roles/permissions?

Comment: Yeah i have root access. Is  it possible that IP's changed after a reboot? Also, should i try to ping the server ip from a client ip that isnt working?

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with any aspects of your system, so you should try any and everything possible.

Comment: I can ping the db server successfully. So its not that.

Comment: If you nmap the server, does it show port 3306 open?

Comment: Yep 3306 is open, the java app is trying to access the info, just not successful

Comment: SO i think it must be on the mysql server side. Not the java applications. No IP's changed, so something else did.